# Stored procedure works on MySQL workbench, but not in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm testing a database where i have 3 tables, number 1 is storing user information, number 2 is storing the latitude and longitude for different cities, and there's a 3rd table storing the location of a user and it's distance to the closest city. The 3rd table has a composite key from primary keys of the other two tables. 
I have written a stored procedure in mysql workbench that takes in  5 variables then it inserts data into the 3rd table, here's the code using some random variables:

```
SET @lat55 = 36.8451995849609;
SET @lng55 = 54.428798675537;
SET @city55 = 'Rasht';
SET @state55 = 'Gilan';
SET @user_id55 = 70440675;


DELIMITER //  
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS do1 //
CREATE PROCEDURE do1 (IN id INT, IN state VARCHAR(25), IN city VARCHAR(25),             
IN lat DECIMAL(15,13),IN lng DECIMAL(15,12))
BEGIN

`  `DECLARE dmini DECIMAL(5,1);
    DECLARE lmini INT;

    SELECT location_id, ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(lng,lat), geopoint)/1000 AS 
    distance INTO lmini, dmini FROM locations ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;

    INSERT INTO user_has_loc (user_id, location_id, distance, state, city, 
    lat, lng) VALUES (id, lmini, dmini, state, city, lat, lng);
END;
//

CALL do1(@user_id55,@state55,@city55,@lat55,@lng55);
```

it works just fine and inserts into the table, but when i try to call the same procedure with the same variables from python, it does nothing:

```
try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="123456",
        database="v21")
    c = mydb.cursor()

    lat = 36.8451995849609
    lng = 54.428798675537
    city = "Rasht"
    state = "Gilan"
    user = 70440675

    arg = (user, state, city, lat, lng)

    c.callproc('do1', arg)

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
```

It is And when i use

```
c.execute("CALL do1({},{},{},{},{})".format(user, state, city, lat, lng))
```

it gives another Error saying "Unknown column 'Gilan' in 'field list'". The interesting part is that if i insert the same data into the table manually, then when i try to call the procedure from python, it raises the error : "Duplicate entry '70440675-883' for key 'PRIMARY'". so it seems like it tries to insert into the table, but it doesn't save it !!
Can somebody please tell me what am i doing wrong here??

Comment: I'm not experienced with MySQL but should there really be a variable `@pt1` which isn't referenced anywhere else?

Comment: I copied the code above from an earlier version i was working on, it should be @pointt, I will edit it in my question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer ----->> so finally i was able to make it work, the trick was to add mydb.commit() after i call the procedure from python

```
try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="123456",
        database="v21")
    c = mydb.cursor()

    lat = 36.8451995849609
    lng = 54.428798675537
    city = "Rasht"
    state = "Gilan"
    user = 70440675

    arg = (user, state, city, lat, lng)

    c.callproc('do1', arg)
    mydb.commit()

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
```

it's not mentioned in the documentation that we need to use [.commit()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) after using [.callproc()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html) method, especially when all the updating and inserting is being done on the database side. But, it is mentioned in [.commit()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) documentation that

> Since by default Connector/Python does not autocommit, it is important to call this method after every transaction that modifies data for tables that use transactional storage engines.

So my guess is since the procedure tries to manipulate data on the database and it's called from the python client, we need to use .commit() after using .callproc().

Answer (score 0):

My **guess** is that perhaps there are some rounding issues between the 2nd and 3rd queries of the stored procedure. You might consider eliminating the 2nd query altogether, and just change the 3rd query to something like this:

```
SELECT location_id, ST_Distance_Sphere(@pt1, geopoint)/1000 AS distance
INTO @lmini, @mini
FROM locations
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

*I say "something like" because I primarily work in MSSQL lately, and didn't do a lot of SELECT INTO when I was in MySQL more often. *(Specifically, I don't recall if you can alias and into like this.)*

Comment: it tried what you said, but still doesn't work in python, interesting part is it doesn't raise an error anymore, it just doesn't do anything

Comment: Maybe double check the values the proc gets from both calling methods, you could put an `insert into somelog` at the start of the proc and see if the values coming in look different; it almost sounds like the proc is finding nothing close.

Comment: Also, be a little wary of using session/@ variables inside stored procedures; they have connection scope, so proc calls can end up with initial values set elsewhere and/or earlier on the connection. And make sure you correct `@pt1` to `@pointt` in my answer, I started from before you corrected the typo(?) in your question.

Comment: well, i changed the @ variables and declared two separate variables inside the procedure, i also checked whether the procedure receives the input variables or no, which show it does, but it still doesn't insert into the table as before