# Works on MySQL Workbench, but not on Python? two identical codes. But other value

Tags: python, mysql, select

this select works in Workbench and Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="root",
  password="xxxxxxxx",
  database="gnucash"
)

sqlcursor = mydb.cursor()
sqlcursor.execute("""
SELECT  MAX(transactions.num) AS nr , MAX(transactions.enter_date) AS enter, MAX(transactions.post_date) AS post, MAX(transactions.description) AS "beschr", SUM(splits.value_num) AS "Euro"
FROM gnucash.splits
INNER JOIN gnucash.transactions ON gnucash.splits.tx_guid = gnucash.transactions.guid
INNER JOIN gnucash.accounts ON gnucash.splits.account_guid = gnucash.accounts.guid
WHERE transactions.guid IN (
    SELECT transactions.guid FROM gnucash.splits
    INNER JOIN gnucash.transactions ON gnucash.splits.tx_guid = gnucash.transactions.guid
    INNER JOIN gnucash.accounts ON gnucash.splits.account_guid = gnucash.accounts.guid
    WHERE accounts.guid LIKE "f2dd1f1e92cf41f687187d1e73fbc2c9")
AND accounts.guid NOT LIKE "f2dd1f1e92cf41f687187d1e73fbc2c9"
GROUP BY transactions.enter_date
ORDER BY post DESC, nr DESC, enter DESC
LIMIT 30;
""")

rohumsaetze = sqlcursor.fetchall()

print(rohumsaetze)
```

this select works on Workbench, **but not** in Python???

```
SELECT  MAX(transactions.num) AS nr , MAX(transactions.enter_date) AS enter, MAX(transactions.post_date) AS post, MAX(transactions.description) AS "beschr", SUM(splits.value_num) AS "Euro"
FROM gnucash.splits
INNER JOIN gnucash.transactions ON gnucash.splits.tx_guid = gnucash.transactions.guid
INNER JOIN gnucash.accounts ON gnucash.splits.account_guid = gnucash.accounts.guid
WHERE transactions.guid IN (
    SELECT transactions.guid FROM gnucash.splits
    INNER JOIN gnucash.transactions ON gnucash.splits.tx_guid = gnucash.transactions.guid
    INNER JOIN gnucash.accounts ON gnucash.splits.account_guid = gnucash.accounts.guid
    WHERE accounts.guid LIKE "1df66c60180c4f3cb5cc080c1e7d4834")
AND accounts.guid NOT LIKE "1df66c60180c4f3cb5cc080c1e7d4834"
GROUP BY transactions.enter_date
ORDER BY post DESC, nr DESC, enter DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

only the "%Sparda%" and "%Commerz%" is the different. On Workbench works fine but i needed python. I have try to make the Statement with root, how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751358/stored-procedure-works-on-mysql-workbench-but-not-in-python). But without success. And above all there is no error. How to find the error? Find the error?

I have already rewritten the code 3 times. Maybe someone has an idea how to write it differently? That it works.

thanks to you

Comment: Show how you're executing it in Python. It may be a quoting problem.

Comment: Put the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: sorry my mistake. Question is now updated, with all the code.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Try changing `%S` to `%%S`

Comment: unfortunately no. with print only print an empty list. and the Workbench works. no idea why... it might be possible to make a SELECT from a Python variable?

Comment: Of course it's possible. When the function receives its parameters, it doesn't matter where they came from.

Comment: There's no difference between `func("abc")` and `variable = "abc"; func(variable)`

Comment: But since there's no difference, it won't solve the problem.

Comment: What happened to `%Sparda%` in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related with the "%S" of Sparda, in python it might be parsed as a string placeholder

Comment: That's what I thought, but I don't think they should be processed inside SQL strings.

Comment: good idea. i changed the `name` by the `guid`. still the same.

Comment: @DKGermany What does that have to do with this answer? It's about the special placeholder `%s` used by `cursor.execute()`, the column name is irrelevant.

Comment: as you can see now, the code with `guid`  written. And the list is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

**I have the Answer.** It's something with the "`import mysql.connector`"

i try with the same code but with a other connector "`import pymysql`". And it works! Don't know why, but now the SQL-Statment can make a select.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='dariokoceic', passwd='XXXXXXXX', db='gnucash')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""
SELECT  MAX(transactions.num) AS nr , transactions.enter_date AS enter, MAX(transactions.post_date) AS post, MAX(transactions.description) AS "beschr", SUM(splits.value_num) AS "Euro", MAX(splits.quantity_denom) 
FROM gnucash.splits
INNER JOIN gnucash.transactions ON gnucash.splits.tx_guid = gnucash.transactions.guid
INNER JOIN gnucash.accounts ON gnucash.splits.account_guid = gnucash.accounts.guid
WHERE transactions.guid IN (
    SELECT transactions.guid FROM gnucash.splits
    INNER JOIN gnucash.transactions ON gnucash.splits.tx_guid = gnucash.transactions.guid
    INNER JOIN gnucash.accounts ON gnucash.splits.account_guid = gnucash.accounts.guid
    WHERE accounts.guid LIKE "1df66c60180c4f3cb5cc080c1e7d4834")
AND accounts.guid NOT LIKE "1df66c60180c4f3cb5cc080c1e7d4834"
GROUP BY transactions.enter_date
ORDER BY post DESC, nr DESC, enter DESC
LIMIT 30;
""")

print(cur.description)

for row in cur:
    print(row)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE. I have discovered the problem. The mysql.connector would like to have exactly the same column when you use GROUP BY, must be on the SELECT in the first place.
and the code should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='dariokoceic', passwd='XXXXXXXX', db='gnucash')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""
SELECT transactions.enter_date AS enter, MAX(transactions.num) AS nr, MAX(transactions.post_date) AS post, MAX(transactions.description) AS "beschr", SUM(splits.value_num) AS "Euro", MAX(splits.quantity_denom) 
FROM gnucash.splits
INNER JOIN gnucash.transactions ON gnucash.splits.tx_guid = gnucash.transactions.guid
INNER JOIN gnucash.accounts ON gnucash.splits.account_guid = gnucash.accounts.guid
WHERE transactions.guid IN (
    SELECT transactions.guid FROM gnucash.splits
    INNER JOIN gnucash.transactions ON gnucash.splits.tx_guid = gnucash.transactions.guid
    INNER JOIN gnucash.accounts ON gnucash.splits.account_guid = gnucash.accounts.guid
    WHERE accounts.guid LIKE "1df66c60180c4f3cb5cc080c1e7d4834")
AND accounts.guid NOT LIKE "1df66c60180c4f3cb5cc080c1e7d4834"
GROUP BY transactions.enter_date
ORDER BY post DESC, nr DESC, enter DESC
LIMIT 30;
""")

print(cur.description)

for row in cur:
    print(row)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

i have only swapped this sentence...

```
SELECT transactions.enter_date AS enter, MAX(transactions.num) AS nr,
```